# How to order by a formula in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query:

```
SELECT locations.id, 1609.34 * 3956 * 2 * 
            ASIN(
                SQRT(
                    POWER(
                        SIN(
                            (55.170000 - abs(locations.latitude)) 
                        * pi() / 180 / 2), 2) + 
                        COS(55.170000 * pi() / 180 ) *
                        COS(abs
                            (locations.latitude) * pi() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-7.400000 - (locations.longitude)) *  pi() / 180 / 2), 2)
            ) 
            ) as result 
        FROM locations order by result asc limit 10;
```

What I want is to get only the locations.id column, but at the same time order it by the formula so I can easily use hibernate.

I do not want to have in the select result table the "result" new column.

How can I do this in MySQL ?

Comment: so what is the problem?

Comment: In the result table I also have the temporary "result" column which I do not want to have. I want to include the big formula only in the order by <formula>. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wrap your query in another query

```
SELECT 
    Location
FROM (  
    SELECT 
        locations.id as Location, 
        1609.34 * 3956 * 2 * 
                ASIN(
                    SQRT(
                        POWER(
                            SIN(
                                (55.170000 - abs(locations.latitude)) 
                            * pi() / 180 / 2), 2) + 
                            COS(55.170000 * pi() / 180 ) *
                            COS(abs
                                (locations.latitude) * pi() / 180) * POWER(SIN((-7.400000 - (locations.longitude)) *  pi() / 180 / 2), 2)
                ) 
                ) as result 
    FROM locations order by result asc limit 10
) AS L
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. I will study your code.

Comment: What if the SELECT statement is `SELECT *` ? how would you remove the 'result' column in the outer SELECT?